# Convert ObjectGuid from AD to GUID powershell

Tags: powershell, guid

I cannot understand why this does not work in PowerShell v4:

```
New-Object -TypeName System.Guid((New-Object -TypeName DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher -Property @{ Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=$env:COMPUTERNAME))" }).FindOne().Properties.Item('objectguid')[0])
```

when this works in PowerShell v5:

```
[Guid]::New((New-Object -TypeName DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher -Property @{ Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=$env:COMPUTERNAME))" }).FindOne().Properties.Item('ObjectGuid')[0])
```

But unfortantly the 'New' method does not exist in PowerShell v4.  But, the first example should work.  the arg is a Byte Array, as the it should accept: [GUID MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx).  But i get an error that says:

```
Cannot find an overload for "Guid" and the argument count: "16"
```

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work, must have been using the wrong constructor?  i don't know but this works:

```
New-Object -TypeName System.Guid -ArgumentList @(,(New-Object -TypeName DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher -Property @{ Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=$env:COMPUTERNAME))" }).FindOne().Properties.Item('objectguid')[0])
```

Hope it helps someone, sometime, somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled on this problem myself. 
The reason

```
New-Object Guid @(,$guidByteArray)
```

works while

```
New-Object Guid $guidByteArray
```

doesn't is due to how powershell v4 (and lower) parses what you've provided.

The former is interpreted as passing a literal array into New-Object's -ArgumentList parameter.

The latter is interpreted as passing a list of arguments into the New-Object's -ArgumentList parameter.

The Guid(Byte[]) constructor takes one parameter, and as the error message says, there are no constructors for the Guid structure which accept 16 parameters of any type.

In powershell v5, the Guid::New() constructor is properly identifying that you intend to pass an array, rather then a list of arguments, and selecting the correct overload.